# What do we call a male domestic servant?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

What do we call a male domestic servant?

Maid is a female domestic servant. I don’t think “butler” is the equivalent term for a male, as butler is considered as the most important servant serving in a large house and who is also in charge of other employees.

Answer (score 1):

For interior, domestic duties there are several roles under the Butler:

1. Valet
2. First Footman
3. Second Footman
4. Footman
5. Page boy

See [Victorian Domestic Servant Hierarchy and Wage Scale](http://www.waynesthisandthat.com/servantwages.htm) web page for more detailed descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with [**manservant**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manservant)?

> : a male servant

(From Merriam-Webster)

Comment: Glad to help. *Thank you* comments are [not encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment) on this site; [upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) useful answers and [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the one that works best for you is encouraged. It is also good to wait for a day or so before accepting, in case a better answer shows up.